# How to start a service (`IServiceCollection`) at startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, esb

I have a singleton service I want running at startup rather waiting for some `Controller` to construct the service via Dependency Injection.

The service processes data from a service bus and it doesn't seem to right rely on client traffic. What is the cleanest way to initialise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you instantiate the service normally, then pass a reference of it to `AddSingleton()` method.

```
var someRepository = new SomeRepository(/*pass in configuration and dependencies*/);

// pass instance of the already instantiated service
services.AddSingleton<ISomeRespository>(someRepository);
```

**Edit**

Or a warmup extension method:

```
public static class WarmupServiceProviderExtensions
{
    public static void WarmUp(this IServiceProvider app)
    {
        // Just call it to resolve, no need to safe a reference
        app.RequestService<ISomeRepository>();
    }
}
```

and in your Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IServiceProvider app) 
{
    app.UseXyz(...);

    // warmup/initailize your services
    app.WarmUp();
}
```

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is "pass in configuration and dependencies" as my `SomeRepository` has dependencies of its own (a message bus)

Comment: Well, passing it as dependency to Configure just feels dirty. Of course you can have a warmup extension method or `IServiceProvider` and call it in Configure

Comment: Nice. I guess a lazy coder with only one thing to warm up could just call `app.RequestService<ISomeRepository>()` but the warm up extension feels the best

Answer (score 1):

Oh, just reference it in `Startup.cs` even if you do not need to configure it.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Has message bus connection
    services.AddSingleton<ISomeRespository, SomeRepository>();

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(... ISomeRespository db)
{
```

Duh :)